# excel freeze row and first 3 columns from scrolling down

Tags: excel

I have looked for this but can't find the answer to this question. I want to freeze the first three columns and the first row from scrolling down. I can freeze the top row from scrolling down and the first three from scrolling right but not both from scrolling down.

```
xxxxxxxxxx
xxx-------
xxx-------
xxx-------
```

Basically, I want the xxx's to not scroll down while the ------ scroll down. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible:
Imagine your first `xxx-----` is in row 2. If you scroll down, the `xxx` stay but the `----` go down, then this would mean that `xxx` stays in row 2, but `----` would move to row 3, row 4, … (or do I understand your request wrongly?).

Comment: Ya exactly, basically the xxx's don't move when i scroll down, but if you think it's not possible I guess it's not. Seem's like something that should be in excel though.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons for asking for this, but currently the situation is very clear: next to cell A2, there is B2; next to A3 there is B3. Your proposal would cause: next to cell A2 there is B3; next to A3 there is B4. Aren't you afraid this might cause quite some confusion?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I get : View > New window > Rearrange both window & FreezeTopRow for 1 window

Hope that helps. (: